# cannot access local variable 'nr' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
def NearByDoc(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        nearby = request.POST.get("NearBy")
        nr = nearby
    return render(request,'nearbyDoc.html',{'nrb':NearBy_Doctor.objects.all(),'near':nr})
```

How can I pass "nr" variable to the dictionary?
Help me to solve this. I'm new at Django.

Answer (score 2):

I think your error may occur when `request.method != "POST"`, in which condition, `nr` is not initialized. I think the following changes may be helpful:

```py
def NearByDoc(request):
    nr = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        nearby = request.POST.get("NearBy")
        nr = nearby
    return render(request,'nearbyDoc.html' {'nrb':NearBy_Doctor.objects.all(),'near':nr})
```

Initialize `nr` to whatever value you want.